# Does the "Guest" network of Apple's Airport Extreme router weaken the signal of the regular 5GHz network?

Tags: router, wifi-configuration, airport-extreme

Does the "Guest" network of Apple's Airport Extreme router weaken the signal of the regular 5GHz network, or is it fine to have on? They seem to be on the same channel without an option to change that.

I'd like to optimize the "Icarus 5GHz" network, both are coming from the same Airport device.

[image]

Comment: If it interfered with the main network why would Apple even offer it as an option let alone every other router manufacturer out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the guest network does not weaken the signal of the main network, nor can its transmissions collide with the main network's transmissions.

AirPort Extremes only have one radio per band, so the guest network is published by the same radio as the main network. This requires it to be on the same channel, because an AP radio can't go jumping around between channels or it would miss packets.

An idle guest network won't affect your main network's performance. You can password-protect the guest network if you want to keep unauthorized guests from using your bandwidth.

I believe the AirPort Extreme already prioritizes main network traffic or limits guest network traffic in some way. I definitely see higher latency when I accidentally connect to my AirPort Extreme's guest network.